# Exact Twitter search in Android

Tags: android, twitter

I have implemented a Twitter search in my android app, when I search for a string I get all tweets associated, but I only want one result showing only the string I'm looking for, not the entire tweets.

For example, if I'm looking for "MTVAwards" I get something like "Hi @MTVAwards, regards from Michigan"... The result I want is "MTVAwards" if exists, if not a button to create it.

I´m only looking for hashtags (#)

Thanks

Comment: Surround you text query with quotes "MTVAwards" to get exact results. [Source](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search). To search for hashtags you add a hashtag symbol #MTVAwards

Comment: Thanks @user3249477, but using quotes ("") I get again the complete tweet where the text I search appears, I need only one result if the text is found in Tweeter